# Convert .csv to Json, more than one property value

Tags: json, r, csv, converters

I am trying to convert a spread sheet to a json file that is to be read with Exhibit 3.0. Here is a sample spread sheet (skills of candidates 1-6):

```
label   Skills
1       SQL
2       SQL, SAS
3   
4       MS Office
5       MS Office, SQL
6       SAS
```

Whenever I try to convert I get:

```
[{"label":"1","Skills":"SQL"},
{"label":"2","Skills":"SQL, SAS"},
{"label":"3","Skills":""},
{"label":"4","Skills":"MS Office"},
{"label":"5","Skills":"MS Office, SQL"},
{"label":"6","Skills":"SAS"}]
```

What I need is (note the square brackets):

```
 [{"label":"1","Skills":"SQL"},
{"label":"2","Skills":["SQL", "SAS"]},
{"label":"3","Skills":""},
{"label":"4","Skills":"MS Office"},
{"label":"5","Skills":["MS Office", "SQL"]},
{"label":"6","Skills":"SAS"}]
```

Only this way Exhibit will accept that a candidate can have more than one skill. Is there a way of creating these square brackets? Or is there another way I could design the spread sheet so Exhibit would recognize that candidate no.2 has two skills? I have been working with R and Excel and so far been out of luck finding a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: it really depends how that "Skills" column is layed out - is it a list, a vector or just a character of the whole thing? Use `dput()` on the data so it's possible to see, and paste it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to reproduce your code and loks like your problem is that you are considering Skills as a column of characters, if you consider every element as a vector, then the function toJSON from `jsonlite`package does it well and puts the "[ ]" when converting an array to JSON

```
df <- data.frame(
  label=1:6, 
  Skills2=c("SQL","SQL, SAS","","MS Office","MS Office, SQL","SAS"),
  stringsAsFactors=F)

df$Skills <- strsplit(df$Skills2, ", ")
df$Skills2 <- NULL

toJSON(df)
```

I hope it works for your

```
[{"label":1,"Skills":["SQL"]},
{"label":2,"Skills":["SQL","SAS"]},
{"label":3,"Skills":[]},
{"label":4,"Skills":["MS Office"]},
{"label":5,"Skills":["MS Office","SQL"]},
{"label":6,"Skills":["SAS"]}]
```